# Every triangulation on a disk is orientable.

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation, orientation

Since a disk doesn't contain a Möbius or any other non orientable surface, it is orientable. I want to prove it rigorously by showing every triangulation on a disk is orientable. For this, I was trying to use an induction. For example, If $D=T_1\cup T_2 \cdots\cup T_n$ is a triangulation on a disk, then we can construct $D$ by edge pairing the triangles. Thus, from the facts $T_1$ is orientable and $T_1\cup T_2 \cdots\cup T_j$ is orientable, I one to deduce that the whole triangulation is orientable. However, since the ways of edge pairing are not unique, I cannot make progress.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your disk has a moebius band, it has a one-sided circle.  So you need something like the Jordan Curve Theorem.  Homology + Poincare duality would suffice, as well.  Anything of that form.

Comment: Is there no way to prove it without using such concepts? Is it impossible to progeress the above sketch of a proof?